# Yii2: Not loading JS scripts when I open an ajax popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a BO with an update button. That button opens a popup:

Controller

```
    ...
    return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
```

_form.php

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\assets\jsListAsset;
use app\models\_base\Product;

jsListAsset::register($this);
```

jsListAsset.php

```
class jsListAsset extends AssetTemplate
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/style.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/functions.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'app\assets\AppAsset'
    ];
}
```

when I click for the first time on the update button the popup works fine and my JS script works but when I close and open it again (the same update button or another different) the JS doesn't work. Why is that?

Is working OK in my docker and in a preprod environment but not in prod environment.

Observations: I see the JS script inserted at the end of the code in the main page where is the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach event handlers on elements that are dynamically created.
ie:

```
$('body').on('click', '#sample-id', function(){...//handle event here...});
```

Comment: Hi Kalu, thanks for the answer but doesn't work either. I never enter there.

Comment: share the js for modal dialog